# How can i pass data from one component to another using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm struggling to understand how can I use `useContext` to pass currency to CurrencyData component.
I tried to use ContextProvider with useContext but i wasn't able to make it work.

Currency.js

```
export const Currency = () => {

    const [currency, setCurrency] = useState('');

    const onCurrencyChange = (e) => {
        setCurrency(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
            <div>
                <select onChange={onCurrencyChange}>
                    <option value="usd">USD</option>
                    <option value="eur">EUR</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        );
}
```

Header.js

```
export const Header = () => {

    return (
            <header className="App-header">
                <Currency />
            </header>
        );
}
```

App.js

```
function App() {


  return (
        <div className="App">
          <Header></Header>
          <CurrencyData currency={currency}></CurrencyData >
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use it some what like this:

globalContext.js

```
import {createContext} from 'react';

export const MyContext = createContext();
```

App.js

```
import {useState, createContext} from 'react';
import {MyContext} from 'globalContext.js';
    

function App() {
 
 const [currency, setCurrency] = useState('')
 
  return (
        <div className="App">
          <MyContext.Provider value={[currency,setCurrency]}>
            <Header></Header>
            <CurrencyData currency={currency}></CurrencyData>
          </MyContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Curreny.js

```
import {useContext} from 'react';
import {MyContext} from 'globalContext.js';

    export const Currency = () => {
    
        const [currency, setCurrency] = useContext(MyContext)
    
        const onCurrencyChange = (e) => {
            setCurrency(e.target.value);
        }
    
        return (
                <div>
                    <select onChange={onCurrencyChange}>
                        <option value="usd">USD</option>
                        <option value="eur">EUR</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            );
    }
```